# Sikuli logging settings

Tags: java, logging, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I'm using sikuli-script.jar in my java application. It writes a lot of logging messages in the console. So, I want to disable logging or change the logging level. How I can do this? What logging library is used there and how it can be configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run some Sikuli script a few times and never noticed any verbose output.  I think you can **[override it](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Debug.html)** by passing to the JVM an option like this:

```
-Dsikuli.Debug=ERROR
```

or

```
-Dsikuli.Debug=0
```

This is an untested answer.  You'll have to try it yourself.

Comment: Debug=0 doesn't work. It disables info messages when Debug=-2. This is pretty strange behavior. http://code.google.com/p/liuyn/source/browse/trunk/Sikuli-script/src/main/java/edu/mit/csail/uid/Debug.java

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Java, you may want to check out [Sikuli-API](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/) instead.  It tries to be more of a standard Java library.

Sikuli-API uses [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org), so you just connect it to whatever logging framework you use (I like [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) a lot), and it will use that configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can include this line in your script at the top to disable action logs like mouse click logs on stdout :D

```
Settings.ActionLogs=0
```

Comment: Settings.ActionLogs returns boolean. Settings.ActionLogs=0 would be compile error I think

Answer (score 0):

In the sikuli-java.jar, sikuli-basics allows access to some configurable options:

Settings.ActionLogs
Settings.InfoLogs

Either/both can be assigned false to disable logging.

Alternatively, Debug.setLogFile(filename) may be used to redirect output to a file rather than the stdout.

Good luck, sikuli-guy!

Answer (score 0):

For Sikuli 1.1.0 under Mac OS X 10.11.5 and JDK 1.8, this is the only way I can suppress logging when running the script via CLI:

```
java -Dsikuli.Debug=-2 -jar /Applications/SikuliX.app/Contents/Java/sikulix.jar -r /path/to/your/test.sikuli
```

NOTE:

1) You have to set -Dsikuli.Debug to -2 to make it work (thanks @NullPointer)

2) You have to place -Dsikuli.Debug=-2 as a JVM option right after "java" instead of placing it at the end of the command